# How can I find the geodesics on the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 1$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, geodesic

**Definition**

Let's say we have a manifold $M$, and a curve $\gamma : \: I \ni t \rightarrow \gamma(t) \in M$

We call that curve a geodesic $\Leftrightarrow$ the vector field consisting of $\dot{\gamma}(t)$ is parallel along $\gamma$ i.e. $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}} \dot{\gamma} = 0$ along our curve $\gamma$

*Note:* $\nabla$ is the affine connection i.e.

An affine connection on $M$ is a $\mathbb{R}$-double-linear map such, that: $$\nabla : \: \mathcal{X}(M) \times \mathcal{X}(M) \rightarrow \mathcal{X}(M)$$ which for $\forall_{f, g \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M)} \: \forall_{X, Y \in \mathcal{X}(M)}$ fulfills the following conditions:

1. $\nabla_{fX + gY} = f \nabla_X + g \nabla_Y$
2. $\nabla_X (fY) = f \nabla_X Y + (Xf)Y$

*Note:* $\mathcal{X}(M)$ is the family of vector fields on $M$

---

Now, the exercise is: Find the geodesics on the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.

So obviously, this means I guess that our manifold $M$ is that given cylinder.

I know have all of those definitions, but I can't seem to find the practical approach to that.

So my question is: How should I even start?

Comment: Which connection?

Comment: The easy geometric approach starts with 1. An obvious mapping from the Euclidean plane to the cylinder is a local isometry; 2. We know the geodesics in the Euclidean plane.

Comment: @ArcticChar https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_connection

Comment: There are more than one affine connection on any manifold. Which one are you using?

Comment: @ArcticChar The one I've given the definition for here. It's literally the only one we've learned in the course

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang How should I do it step by step?

Comment: You have only the definition of an affine connection, but not a particular one. Different connections give rises to different geodesics.

Comment: @ArcticChar What are some examples of particular affine connections? As for the exercise: It's not stated which particular affine connection is used.

Comment: It will be a good exercise for you to find out which (canonical) connection is associated to a surface embedded in $\mathbb R^3$. It must be stated somewhere in your lecture notes.

Comment: @ArcticChar It's not stated, we've just been told that the definition I gave here is the affine connection and that's it. I've never heard of particular affine connections until you told me here about that. But to be honest, our course isn't like the best course of DG you can have, a lot of important stuff seems to be skipped is something I've noticed by asking here on this forum question related to DG

Comment: But at least you are given examples on how to calculate $\nabla _{\gamma' } \gamma'$?

Comment: @ArcticChar No, not even examples. The lecture was only theory, no examples at all. And the exercise I'm asking here about is from the Tutorials, we have a list of exercises to solve at the blackboard and the Prof told me that I get a B if I solve one more exercise. But as you see, the exercises themselves are very unspecified. And that's all we do in tutorials, we don't do any examples to understand the lecture better. No, we have to straight away know how to solve exercises without a deeper "intuitive" understanding given to us by examples, which as I said are lacking in the lectures

Comment: It’s fair to assume that the cylinder inherits the induced Riemannian metric from $\Bbb R^3$ and the Induced Levi-Civita connection. Go back to @AndrewD.Hwang’s comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have local coordinates on $M$, you can express $\nabla$ as a tensor-like symbol (Christoffel's symbol):
$$
\nabla_{\partial_\mu}\partial_\nu=\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^\sigma\partial_\sigma.
$$

So using the definitions, you can write for $\dot\gamma=\dot\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu$:
$$
\nabla_{\dot\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu}\dot\gamma^\nu\partial_\nu = \dot\gamma^\mu\nabla_{\partial_\mu}\dot\gamma^\nu\partial_\nu = 
\dot\gamma^\mu\left(\dot\gamma^\nu\nabla_{\partial_\mu}\partial_\nu+\partial_\mu\dot\gamma^\nu\partial_\nu\right)=
\dot\gamma^\mu\dot\gamma^\nu\nabla_{\partial_\mu}\partial_\nu+\dot\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\dot\gamma^\nu\partial_\nu.
$$

The first term can be rewritten using Christoffel's symbol, and for the second one we can see that taking the directional derivative twice along the same curve is the same as the second derivative:

$$
\nabla_{\dot\gamma}\dot\gamma = 
\dot\gamma^\mu\dot\gamma^\nu\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^\sigma\partial_\sigma+
\ddot\gamma^\sigma\partial_\sigma.
$$

If you want a fixed equation for geodesic, you need to fix the affine connection (or equivalently define Christoffel's symbol). Different connection create different topologies. However, there exists a special unique affine connection called [Levi-Civita connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection), which preserves metric (inherited from the $\mathbb R^3$ embedding) and is torsion free. Usually, Levi-Civita connection is what is assumed 99.9% of the time. You can follow [Wikipedia derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection#Christoffel_symbols) to show that
$$
{\displaystyle \Gamma _{jk}^{l}={\tfrac {1}{2}}g^{lr}\left(\partial _{k}g_{rj}+\partial _{j}g_{rk}-\partial _{r}g_{jk}\right)}.
$$

Now, if you introduce local coordinates on the cylinder. You are able to calculate $g_{\mu\nu}$, $\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^\sigma$ and get a 2nd order ODE on $\gamma^\mu$. Btw, if you choose nice local coordinates (cylindrical), the calculations, ODE and the solution will be extremely easy.